# Serialization with different programs c#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter

I have 2 programs that use serialization, in 2 different projects.
Program 1 serializes and deserializes an array of a class called Quiz.Both project have the the Quiz Class.
Program 2 only deserializes what Program 1 serialized:

```
private void loadSerialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("DataFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        Quiz[] obj = (Quiz[]) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        for(int i = 0; i< obj.Length; i++)
        {
            quizes.Add(obj[i]);
        }
        stream.Close();
    }

    private void saveSerialize(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {

        Quiz[] obj = quizes.ToArray();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("DataFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

both programs have the "loadSerialize" function while only Program1 has the "saveSerialize" function.
I`m getting a serializationException when I try to deserialize the file in Program2.
Saying that(message erro was in portuguese so I translated it to english):
Couldnt find the assembly 'infoAplicadaEnsino, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
How can I deserialize in Program2?

Answer (score 5):

Same class members, name and namespace is not enough for deserialization to work, the assembly must also match, this is how `BinaryFormatter` is designed. You can fix this by extracting `Quiz` class to a separate class library project and reference the new project by both program projects.

Comment: Indeed. There is also lazy option - just add the first exe as reference to the second project.

Comment: Now I`m getting the erro that I cant acess the file because its being used by another process when I try to serialize the object.
Edit: NVM, solved when deleted the previous serialized file.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have 2 copies of the `Quiz` class in the two solutions (or projects). Instead, create a third solution (or project) with a class library project. Class library projects create DLLs instead of EXEs. Move all the things used in common in your 2 solutions (or projects) to this third one and then reference this third project in the existing ones. So you will have only one `Quiz` class (and also only one `loadSerialize` method).

This will not only make your serialization/deserialization work, but will make it easier to keep the things consistent (only one version of `Quiz` to maintain).